# Magento: which catalog_product_flat I need to select from? and what is catalog_product_entity_datetime table?

Tags: magento, data-modeling, entity-attribute-value

To know who are the customers needed to be sent the notification mail and know which are the products remain 2 hours before the deal expired,
I need to select from wishlist, wishlist_item, customer_entity and catalog_product_enity   table which need to join with catelog_product_flat_X 
But there are many catelog_product_flat_X tables (X has from 1 to 64)
How to know which table I need to join with?

Here is the structure of the catalog_product_flat table which has fields "special_to_date" and "visibility" I need

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_flat_1` (
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple',
`cost` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`enable_googlecheckout` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`has_options` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`image_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`links_exist` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`links_purchased_separately` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`links_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`news_from_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`news_to_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`price_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`price_view` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`required_options` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`shipment_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`short_description` text,
`sku` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`sku_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`small_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`small_image_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`special_from_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`special_price` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`special_to_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`tax_class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`thumbnail_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`url_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`url_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`visibility` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`weight` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`weight_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
KEY `IDX_TYPE_ID` (`type_id`),
KEY `IDX_ATRRIBUTE_SET` (`attribute_set_id`),
KEY `IDX_NAME` (`name`),
KEY `IDX_PRICE` (`price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the catalog_product_entity which I can know the id of the product (entity_id)

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity` (
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`entity_type_id` smallint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple',
`sku` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`has_options` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`required_options` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE` (`entity_type_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),
KEY `sku` (`sku`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Product Entities';
```

and what is catalog_product_entity_datetime table? I see it also store the same value to the special_to_date's value in the value field

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime` (
`value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`value` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_ATTRIBUTE` (`attribute_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_STORE` (`store_id`),
KEY `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_PRODUCT_ENTITY` (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11873 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please help me how to do it.

Thanks in advanced,
Rithy

Answer (score 2):

You should use magento catalog/product methods for this, not a raw sql query. 
so start at the Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() and add joins until you get the data you want; the catalog_flat tables and any other table are only meant to use internally by magento.
the flat tables are created by magento from the EAV schema performance purposes.

Comment: Great answer! thank you!. So, I don't need to join with flat table and what are the table I could use to join?

Comment: You can find the table name from the corresponding magento entity: $this->getTable('catalogrule/rule_product_price'); if you start from the product collection you don't need to know the name of the product table, you could use 'main_table' instead of the product table name.

Answer (score 1):

Magento's catalog product data structure implements the *Entity-Attribute-Value* model.  You need to read up on EAV (ref [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)), then consult the Magento [database diagrams](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram#the_magento_eav_data_model).

Comment: I also found [these articles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value) useful as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in, this may help others so I wanted to put some notes up.

I need to pull cat #'s in the **cart** to fire off a bool event.  The flat tables seem unreliable IMHO.  Flats are presented for performance and I don't have a grasp on how Mage uses them,  and don't care generally.

Compound that with the overwhelming radical changes each update on the DB, template, everything - it gets scary.

So here are 2 queries to think about.

```
# get basic product ID from the sku (via something like this : $_item->getSku() ) - returns ID = 122 in my case
select entity_id from `magento_store`.`catalog_product_entity` where sku = 'THE_SKU';

## Use that value to tie to the cat index as such:
SELECT * FROM `magento_store`.`catalog_category_product_index` where product_id = 122; # returns 61 and 62 in my case, the matching cat id #s in the admin.
```

Consider a join of course.

So in this example the `entity_id` returned is the product id and `category_id` is the cat #'s. Using 1.4.1 right now.

Be very careful I have found malicious errors in the core system. Magento is bad mojo.

So hitting on the original question - it is queries like this where you can start joining your own info together for specific needs under the flats/cache. Luckily the tables are kinda labeled to help.  Not an easy task - not impossible either.  I recommend using the carious MVC/similar functionality when ever you can.

Cheers!

Update: Appears the flat table # is the store number (duh). It should match the # in the uri such as

```
index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/store/2/
```

woudl be flat2 table.